# any ideas about how to program an automated signed contract

Tags: java, automation

I have a small company and I want all the work to be professional, I was thinking if there is a way to scan the contract (signed) and I fill the name of the customer, phone number, address and day's date in some interface then I print the contract signed with all info I entered (every info has specific location in the contract).
is this possible? what would be the best way to do it.

p.s. I'm a beginner java programmer

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are a beginner java programmer I would avoid scanning an image at all costs, it in and of itself isn't *too* hard however what you want to do with it is; you would need to branch off first. I would suggest searching for things like IO in java and how to create an Image in java, before considering this large feat.
If you feel as though you are ready here is some code which could get you on your way: 
    `try {
    Robot robo = new Robot();
    }catch(Exception e){}
    //Do what you would like to prepare the contract
    BufferedImage contract;
    contract = robo.getScreenCapture(new Rectangle(screenWidth, screenHeight));
    ImageIO.write(contract, "format e.g. png", FilePathandName);`

I respect your curiosity and goals though ;)